# Having a problem adding a margin or padding to the li tag when next to an image. would like to see small indent whenever displaying the list items

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at my code:

```css
.pclass {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  background-color: #536A42;
  font-family: inherit;
  left-margin: 3%;
}

.className {
  max-width: 19%;
  max-height: 19%;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 12px 3px 0px;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul.a {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 8%;
  background-color: #536A42;
  font-family: inherit;
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<div id="General" class="container-fluid" style="display: block">
  <div class="pclass">
    <h3>General Services</h3>
    <img src="http://www.almostyouinhomeanimalcare.com/assets/images/Frame%2016.jpg" alt="General Services" class="className">We provide in your home care for many animals. Please find descriptions of services on the page dedicated to each animal.<br>
    <br> In general we provided in home care for domestic animals: equines, livestock, poultry, dogs, cats, and small animals. We do not provide care services to exotic animals.<br>
    <br> We provide:<br>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Daily Care</li>
      <li>Walking</li>
      <li>Cuddling and Kitty Book reading</li>
      <li>Stall Cleaning</li>
      <li>Barn Maid Service</li>
      <li>Ground work for equines</li>
      <li>Taxi Service</li>
      <li>Trip to the Veterinarian</li>
      <li>Trip to the Groomer</li>
      <li>Trip to Play Days</li>
      <li>Other trips you may require</li>
      <li>Custody Swap</li>
      <li>Do you share a pet with an ex and you would rather not take that trip? We will do if for you.</li>
      <li>Various livestock services and care</li>
      <li>Food and supply delivery</li>
    </ul>
    We are adding new services regularly. Please call us to discuss services you don't see listed or would like to suggest.
  </div>
  <div class="pclass">
    <h4>General Service Fees</h4>
    <img src="http://www.almostyouinhomeanimalcare.com/assets/images/Frame%2016.jpg" alt="General Service Fees" class="className">Basic Daily Visit- $22.50 hour<br>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Poop scooping/litter box cleaning</li>
      <li>Wellness check (normal eating, normal activity, eating, nor obvious signs of distress or discomfort)</li>
      <li>Feeding</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Let out/Let in if appropriate</li>
      <li>Hutch or cage cleaning</li>
      <li>Fill water bottles, refresh shavings, fill feed containers</li>
      <li>Feed Fish</li>
      <li>Face Time/Zoom/other connection up to 5 minutes ($1.00 each additional minute)</li>
      <li>Other Services can be discussed</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to display a small margin that is consistent whether the list items line up next to the image or on the left side of the page.

Comment: Please don't use external code references when a StackOverflow does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only added a bit more left margin on ul.a just to keep them all a consistent distance away. Could always lower it and limit the picture size as well.

```css
.pclass {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  background-color: #536A42;
  font-family: inherit;
  left-margin: 3%;
}

.className {
  max-width: 19%;
  max-height: 19%;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 12px 3px 0px;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul.a {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 19%;
  background-color: #536A42;
  font-family: inherit;
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<div id="General" class="container-fluid" style="display: block">
  <div class="pclass">
    <h3>General Services</h3>
    <img src="http://www.almostyouinhomeanimalcare.com/assets/images/Frame%2016.jpg" alt="General Services" class="className">We provide in your home care for many animals. Please find descriptions of services on the page dedicated to each animal.<br>
    <br> In general we provided in home care for domestic animals: equines, livestock, poultry, dogs, cats, and small animals. We do not provide care services to exotic animals.<br>
    <br> We provide:<br>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Daily Care</li>
      <li>Walking</li>
      <li>Cuddling and Kitty Book reading</li>
      <li>Stall Cleaning</li>
      <li>Barn Maid Service</li>
      <li>Ground work for equines</li>
      <li>Taxi Service</li>
      <li>Trip to the Veterinarian</li>
      <li>Trip to the Groomer</li>
      <li>Trip to Play Days</li>
      <li>Other trips you may require</li>
      <li>Custody Swap</li>
      <li>Do you share a pet with an ex and you would rather not take that trip? We will do if for you.</li>
      <li>Various livestock services and care</li>
      <li>Food and supply delivery</li>
    </ul>
    We are adding new services regularly. Please call us to discuss services you don't see listed or would like to suggest.
  </div>
  <div class="pclass">
    <h4>General Service Fees</h4>
    <img src="http://www.almostyouinhomeanimalcare.com/assets/images/Frame%2016.jpg" alt="General Service Fees" class="className">Basic Daily Visit- $22.50 hour<br>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Poop scooping/litter box cleaning</li>
      <li>Wellness check (normal eating, normal activity, eating, nor obvious signs of distress or discomfort)</li>
      <li>Feeding</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Let out/Let in if appropriate</li>
      <li>Hutch or cage cleaning</li>
      <li>Fill water bottles, refresh shavings, fill feed containers</li>
      <li>Feed Fish</li>
      <li>Face Time/Zoom/other connection up to 5 minutes ($1.00 each additional minute)</li>
      <li>Other Services can be discussed</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to embed my jsfiddle link because no matter what I did to format the code e.g., add 4 or 8 spaces to the front I would receive an error preventing me from continuing.

Comment: Error I received when trying to embed all my code:
"Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code)."

Comment: StackOverflow requires the person asking the question to have at least a certain amount of written words in correlation to their code in question. For example you can't type "Fix this." and a million lines of code. You probably just went over the limit, either too few words explaining what you needed help with or your code was too long.

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be achieved using

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

```css
.pclass {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  background-color: #536A42;
  font-family: inherit;
  left-margin: 3%;
}

.className {
  max-width: 19%;
  max-height: 19%;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 12px 3px 0px;
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul.a {
  font-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 8%;
  background-color: #536A42;
  font-family: inherit;
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div id="General" class="container-fluid" style="display: block">
  <div class="pclass">
    <h3>General Services</h3>
    <img src="http://www.almostyouinhomeanimalcare.com/assets/images/Frame%2016.jpg" alt="General Services" class="className">We provide in your home care for many animals. Please find descriptions of services on the page dedicated to each animal.<br>
    <br> In general we provided in home care for domestic animals: equines, livestock, poultry, dogs, cats, and small animals. We do not provide care services to exotic animals.<br>
    <br> We provide:<br>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Daily Care</li>
      <li>Walking</li>
      <li>Cuddling and Kitty Book reading</li>
      <li>Stall Cleaning</li>
      <li>Barn Maid Service</li>
      <li>Ground work for equines</li>
      <li>Taxi Service</li>
      <li>Trip to the Veterinarian</li>
      <li>Trip to the Groomer</li>
      <li>Trip to Play Days</li>
      <li>Other trips you may require</li>
      <li>Custody Swap</li>
      <li>Do you share a pet with an ex and you would rather not take that trip? We will do if for you.</li>
      <li>Various livestock services and care</li>
      <li>Food and supply delivery</li>
    </ul>
    We are adding new services regularly. Please call us to discuss services you don't see listed or would like to suggest.
  </div>
  <div class="pclass">
    <h4>General Service Fees</h4>
    <img src="http://www.almostyouinhomeanimalcare.com/assets/images/Frame%2016.jpg" alt="General Service Fees" class="className">Basic Daily Visit- $22.50 hour<br>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Poop scooping/litter box cleaning</li>
      <li>Wellness check (normal eating, normal activity, eating, nor obvious signs of distress or discomfort)</li>
      <li>Feeding</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Let out/Let in if appropriate</li>
      <li>Hutch or cage cleaning</li>
      <li>Fill water bottles, refresh shavings, fill feed containers</li>
      <li>Feed Fish</li>
      <li>Face Time/Zoom/other connection up to 5 minutes ($1.00 each additional minute)</li>
      <li>Other Services can be discussed</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```